# Why is Powershell Import Data placing an empty row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm using a Powershell script to import API data into SQL Server. At the beginning of the script, the table within the database is truncated--

```powershell
$TruncateTable = @"
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
"@
    
Invoke-sqlcmd @params -Query $TruncateTable
```

Then, the data is imported into SQL Server using a foreach loop with a nested if-else statement and some regex to isolate needed data.

```powershell
foreach ($r in $roles) {
    $InsertRoleResults = @"
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1]([roleID],[roleLocation],[roleName])
VALUES ('$roleId','$rolelocation','$rolename')
"@
        
    # If role value contains brackets: assign variable to data within brackets/ variable to data after brackets
    if($r.name -match '\[')
    {
        [int]$roleId = $r.id
        $rolelocation = $r.name -replace '(\[)(.+)(\])(.+)', '$2'
        $rolename = $r.name -replace '\[.+\]\ ', ''
        Invoke-sqlcmd @params -Query $InsertRoleResults
    
    }
    else
    # if data does not contain brackets, assign Null to rolelocation, entire string to rolename
    {
        [int]$roleId = $r.id
        $rolelocation = $null
        $rolename = $r.name
        Invoke-sqlcmd @params -Query $InsertRoleResults
    }
}
```

In both blocks, I also take the role id number  (`$r.id`) and convert to INT and then reassign to `$roleID`.

Then it inserts into SQL Server. I have this problem where I keep getting this happening:

[image]

If I Write-Host the output of the id values, it starts with 1, not zero. So my question is, where is this zero value coming from?

Comment: So do you get one more row inserted than expected? Is this an extra row or a corrupted existing row? Important: the fact that this zero appears first _does not_ mean it was inserted first. It could have been inserted last.

Comment: I think you need to change the `else` into `elseif (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($r.name))`